How to avoid listen-port conflicts on package installation
I'm working on a private Debian package that deploys a service which binds to port 80.
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo --port 80

I realize almost every other package which serves HTTP is also going to try to bind to port 80.  apache2.service for example, comes with this site enabled by default:
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

Options:

Let the programs race for the bind().  Fastest wins
Add Before=apache2.service to foo.service
Add Conflicts=apache2 to debian/control

With files, we often use update-alternatives to let packages negotiate (or users configure) what package gets to supply a specific file, but do we have anything similar for ports?

If I have apache2 installed and bound to port 80, then apt install nginx, I get:
$ sudo apt install nginx-light
...
Setting up nginx-common (1.18.0-6.1+deb11u3) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service → /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service.
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
Setting up nginx-light (1.18.0-6.1+deb11u3) ...
Not attempting to start NGINX, port 80 is already in use.

So perhaps the solution is to enabling a service conditionally based on whether the port is already bound during installation (though nginx is now enabled, so I presume apache2 and nginx will race on next boot).


Add Conflicts=apache2 to debian/control not an option, because you can perfectly well run have both on the same machine, if configured appropriately. In fact, that's not even that uncommon, with one acting as reverse proxy for the other, hosting applications that require modules that are only available for that specific webserver.

Add Before=apache2.service to foo.service 
that doesn't do anything; Before doesn't do what you seem to think what it does. What it actually does is that if both foo and apache2 are started as dependencies at the same time, their start is ordered. Since nothing will depend on both foo and apache2, that simply won't ever happen.

Let the programs race for the bind(). Fastest wins
I think you meant to write "let the administrator who installs two web servers actually configure them correctly". If that's true, then yes, let's do that. It's what is done.


What one could discuss is whether it's generally sensible to start a server in the installation step, or whether that is up to the administrator to do manually. I'd say there's different arguments for both, and it will depend on the type of server – for example, if I install an X11 server, chances are I want to use that. Whereas if I install an telecommand server (rsh, maybe even sshd), I might want to wait for someone to explicitly enable it. HTTP servers are a bit of "both": there's some expectation of "just works", and some expectation of "not safe until configured".


whether it's generally sensible to start a server in the installation step.    Good point.  Different distros have different opinions with (IIRC) arch making administrators enable any services manually.

